# How to Play Live tv without Using webview IOS 7

Tags: ios, video, http-live-streaming

Hi in my application i want to play a live stream video i have the the live stream video URL. now to trying to normally how to play the video using `URl` in but its not working. Its showing error like.

```
An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer
```

MY video play code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"url"];
     MPMoviePlayerController *mov = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: url];
     self.movieplayer = mov;
     [self.movieplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20, 100, 100)];

     self.movieplayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
     [self.view addSubview:self.movieplayer.view];
     [self.movieplayer prepareToPlay];
     [self.movieplayer pause];

     self.movieplayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;

 }
```

I have used the above code to play the live stream video its not working. I want play live stream video without using the `UIWebView` please tell me is there any possibilities to play live stream with using `UIWebView` or do i need to covert into some other format to play. Please tell me how to resolve this one I'm not finding any proper solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

NSString *url=@"your url";

```
movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self urlencode:url]];
         moviePlayerTemp=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];
         [moviePlayerTemp.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)];
         [moviePlayerTemp prepareToPlay];
             [moviePlayerTemp setShouldAutoplay:YES];
         [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerTemp.view];
-(NSString *)urlencode:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *encodeString=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return encodeString;
}
```

Comment: please tell me where i have to give the url

Comment: just create with nsstring

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathVideo = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathVideo];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL.absoluteURL];
[self.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
[self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeDefault];
[self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];

[self.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 240, 350);
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

And be sure that it will be valid URL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"url"];
```

Comment: please tell where i have to give url in your above code

Comment: replace movieURL with your url which you use to play your video